# Squeezing more speed out MySQL SUM + JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a semi-complex `JOIN` structure to fetch specific information from my MySQL database, based on the orders. First let me give you the SQL Query;

```
SELECT
    #orders.*,
    orders.id,
    customers.lastname,
    customers.priority,
    shipments.status,
    pmv_sl.productmodelvariant_id,
    pmv_sl.nr AS pmv_nr,
    COALESCE(SUM(orderlines.nr), 0) AS orderlines_nr_count,
    COALESCE(SUM(shipment_lines.nr), 0) AS shipment_lines_nr_count
FROM orders
    INNER JOIN  customers       ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN  platforms       ON platforms.id = orders.platform_id
    INNER JOIN  stocklocations  ON stocklocations.id = platforms.stocklocation_id
    LEFT JOIN   orderlines      ON orderlines.order_id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN   shipments       ON shipments.order_id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN   shipment_lines  ON shipment_lines.shipment_id = shipments.id

    # This JOIN, together with shipment_lines, makes the query suddenly very slow (probably because of all the SUM()'s)
    LEFT JOIN   productmodelvariants_stocklocations pmv_sl ON
        pmv_sl.productmodelvariant_id = orderlines.productmodelvariant_id
        AND pmv_sl.stocklocation_id = stocklocations.id
WHERE
    orders.orderstatus_id = 2
    AND orders.order_all_to_shipment = 0
GROUP BY
    orders.id
```

**Problem**

So I've calculated 4 speeds of this query (450 results in all cases);

1. Without `LEFT JOIN shipment_lines` and without `LEFT JOIN productmodelvariants_stocklocations`
2. With `LEFT JOIN shipment_lines` only
3. With `LEFT JOIN productmodelvariants_stocklocations` only
4. With both `2.` and `3.`

And here are the result speeds;

1. 0.146 sec
2. 1.975 sec
3. 0.234 sec
4. 4.619 sec

**Rows in tables**

- Rows in `orderlines` : 24528
- Rows in `shipment_lines` : 6345
- Rows in `productmodelvariants_stocklocations` : 1819

**Conclusion**

As you can see once `2.` and `3.` (in `4.`) both join the race; SQL starts to break sweat.

I wonder if anyone with more (My)SQL knowledge than me knows a way to change the context of the query to boost it a bit.

I also noticed that when doing `4.` and quoting out the `COALESCE(SUM()`'s I easily gain `0.8` to `1.0` seconds.

**Update**

EXPLAIN EXTENDED

[image: EXPLAIN EXTENDED]

Comment: do you have indexes on the `shipment_lines.nr` and `orderlines.nr`? what kind of indexes if so? just a question.

Comment: Good point; I only have `INDEXES` on my primary and relative ID's. How much impact do you think it will have? I don't hope it will impact general performance too much on those tables, as that's mostly the problem with adding too many `INDEXES` :P

Comment: I've added the indexes to both table's `nr` fields. Sadly no improvement in speed. It's exactly the same even. **Edit**: Added to `nr` of `productmodelvariants_stocklocations` too. Also no improvement.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use a *left* join in this case?

Comment: Yes, otherwise some *wanted* results will be excluded. Also, even when I set them all to `INNER` to test. I get back `219` rows, that still run for `3.825 sec` sadly. So relatively it's not even a big gain.

Comment: Also Make sure that all of the fields which take part in the joins and in conditions have indexes on them. What does your `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` show you?

Comment: I've added the output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`.

Comment: dont see the index on this `orders.customer_id` foreign key in the explain. although IF the number of rows is not so big in a table and if database sees that it's better to load the whole table into memory it will do it and do its calcs in mem.

Comment: Weird, because the tree-view in MySQL Workbench says it's there. I also read something on this guy's blog (http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/extended-explain/) that sometimes subqueries might be a faster alternative. Not sure if that will really be something for my *more complex* query tho.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a cross join by failing to specify a join clause on shipments.status

Try reorganizing your query like this:

```
SELECT A.*, 
    orders_id,
    customers.lastname,
    customers.priority,
#    shipments.status,
    pmv_sl.productmodelvariant_id,
    pmv_sl.nr AS pmv_nr,
    orderlines_nr_count,
    shipment_lines_nr_count
FROM (
  SELECT
      #orders.*,
      orders.id AS orders_id,
#      shipments.status,
      COALESCE(SUM(orderlines.nr), 0) AS orderlines_nr_count,
      COALESCE(SUM(shipment_lines.nr), 0) AS shipment_lines_nr_count
  FROM orders
      LEFT JOIN   orderlines      ON orderlines.order_id = orders.id
      LEFT JOIN   shipments       ON shipments.order_id = orders.id
      LEFT JOIN   shipment_lines  ON shipment_lines.shipment_id = shipments.id

  WHERE orders.orderstatus_id = 2
   AND orders.order_all_to_shipment = 0
  GROUP BY 
      orders.id,
      orderlines.productmodelvariant_id,
      stocklocations.id
) orders
    INNER JOIN  customers       ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN  platforms       ON platforms.id = orders.platform_id
    INNER JOIN  stocklocations  ON stocklocations.id = platforms.stocklocation_id
    LEFT JOIN   productmodelvariants_stocklocations pmv_sl ON
      pmv_sl.productmodelvariant_id = orderlines.productmodelvariant_id
      AND pmv_sl.stocklocation_id = stocklocations.id
GROUP BY
    orders.id
```

and then figure out where shipment status goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For some odd reason the first `INNER JOIN` after the `(...) order` fails (`customers.id = orders.customer_id`) (Error code 1054). They somehow don't connect?

Comment: the subselect has to have customer_id in the SELECT clause among the selected fields. `(SELECT orders.customer_id as customer_id,.....) orders INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: do the same for the platform_id as i suggested for customer_id

Comment: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'orderlines.productmodelvariant_id' in 'on clause'`. I did this `orderlines.productmodelvariant_id AS productmodelvariant_id,` inside the SELECT clause too, but it didn't grab it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is doing a cartesian join between orders and shipments, for any given order.  A better approach is to summarize everything to the `order_id` level, before doing the joins:

```
SELECT
    #orders.*,
    orders.id,
    customers.lastname,
    customers.priority,
    shipments.status,
    pmv_sl.productmodelvariant_id,
    pmv_sl.nr AS pmv_nr,
    COALESCE(ol.orderlines_nr_count, 0) AS orderlines_nr_count,
    COALESCE(sl.shipment_lines_nr_count, 0) AS shipment_lines_nr_count
FROM orders
    INNER JOIN  customers       ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN  platforms       ON platforms.id = orders.platform_id
    INNER JOIN  stocklocations  ON stocklocations.id = platforms.stocklocation_id
    LEFT JOIN  
    (select order_id, SUM(orderlines.nr) as orderline_nr_count
     from orderlines
     group by order_id
    ) ol ON ol.order_id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN   shipments       ON shipments.order_id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN
    (select order_id, SUM(shipment_lines.nr) shipment_lines_nr_count
     from shipment_lines 
     group by order_id
    ) sl ON sl.shipment_id = shipments.id

    # This JOIN, together with shipment_lines, makes the query suddenly very slow (probably because of all the SUM()'s)
    LEFT JOIN   productmodelvariants_stocklocations pmv_sl ON
        pmv_sl.productmodelvariant_id = orderlines.productmodelvariant_id
        AND pmv_sl.stocklocation_id = stocklocations.id
WHERE
    orders.orderstatus_id = 2
    AND orders.order_all_to_shipment = 0
GROUP BY
    orders.id
```

This is an approximation, because the only aggregation functions that I see are for orderlines and shipment lines.  If there are more than one shipments per order, for instance, you would have to figure out how to condense that to one status (your original query would arbitrarily choose one, as does this query).

The final `group by` will be unnecessary if you only join together tables/subqueries at the `order_id` level.